# Tensorflow Serving: Is it ok that tensorflow serving relies on file system for storing the models

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I see that the trained models are served from the file systems while using tensorflow serving, is it ok to rely on the file system alone.

Is there a mechanism to restore these models in case the we lose all these files?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom serving image that has your model built into the container that you can deploy using docker and will load your model for serving on startup. Ref: [TensorFlow Serving with Docker](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/docker#creating_your_own_serving_image)

You can also keep your model in Google cloud platform and use the GS path directly to serve models using below command.

```
tensorflow_model_server --port=8080 --model_base_path=gs://bucket_name/folder_models/
```